# How to add labels in my arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, nodes, arrows, paths

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0, 0) [shape=circle,draw] {$\BC^n$};
\node (B) at (4, 0) [shape=circle,draw] {$\BC$};
\draw [->] (A) to [out=60,in=120, bend right]  (B);
\draw [->] (B) to [out=60,in=120, bend right ] (A);
 \path[->]  (A) edge [out=140,in=80,looseness=12]  (A);
 \path[->] (A) edge [out=-190,in=230,looseness=12] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to add labels to my arrows but when I insert the `{some label}` option I get an error when compiling. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways for drawing a labeled graph.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\newcommand\BC{X}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)]
\node (A) at (0, 0) [shape=circle,draw] {$\BC^n$};
\node (B) at (4, 0) [shape=circle,draw] {$\BC$};
\draw [->] (A) to [out=60,in=120, bend right] node[below]{a}  (B);
\draw [->] (B) to [out=60,in=120, bend right ] node[above]{b} (A);
 \path[->]  (A) edge [out=140,in=80,looseness=12] node[above]{c}  (A);
 \path[->] (A) edge [out=-190,in=230,looseness=12] node[below]{d} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  [baseline=(A.base),
   vertex/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=2em},
   auto,>=stealth
  ]
  \node[vertex] (A) {$\BC^n$};
  \node[vertex,right=2cm of A] (B) {$\BC$};
  \path[->] (A) edge[bend right] node[swap]{a} (B)
                edge[loop above] node{c} (A)
                edge[loop left]  node{d} (A)
            (B) edge[bend right] node[swap]{b} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see I had to create a node. I cannot up vote you yet unfortunately. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works with following code:

```
    \draw [axis,<->] (0,2.5) node (yaxis) [above] {F}
|- (2.75,0) node (xaxis) [right] {u};
```

for axis or for line:

```
\draw[dashed] (0.6,0) node[below] {$u_1$} -| (0.6,0.9) node[below] {};
```

Comment: Thanks. Where does this modification enter?

Comment: In your case, I'll take first node from a to b:
\draw[->] (0,0) node[below] {some label} -- (4,0) node[below] {other label};

Comment: Thanks. I do not want label on the nodes. I want labels on the arrows. There are 4 arrows in total and I need to put 4 labels e.g. x,y,z,w. This is when I get errors.